# Can't get Meteor.Error 'details' on client?

Tags: meteor, error-handling

I was googling around but still haven't managed to get the answer.
According to the documentation Meteor.Error should be creatated:

```
new Meteor.Error(error, [reason], [details])
```

I'm throwing the Meteor.Error on server method like this:
On server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    async myMethod(userId, curlng = 'en') {
        ...
        throw new Meteor.Error('CODE', 'reason', 'additional details')
    }
})
```

On client side:

```
Meteor.call('myMethod', userId, TAPi18n.getLanguage(), (error, result) => {
     ...
     if (error) {
        console.log(error)
     }
     ...
})
```

But I can't receive details on client? This field is always 'undefined' in client console.log.

Is there is a way to put some additional data to Error being sent from server to client?

Comment: You have not provided enough code to help you solve this problem. At the very least the method definition and the method call will be necessary.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But the problem I have is simple.
I throw an Error as I described according to the documentation. But I receive details as `undefined` on client, looks like Meteor removes the 'details' put on server.

Comment: But it makes a difference in which context you throw an error with Meteor so the surrounding code (Method, Publication, startup etc.) is still necessary to provide an effective answer.